# push notification using Onesignal error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, onesignal

while trying to create a push Notification using GCM Per device or a group of devices - we are trying to use Onesignal for registration of our android users and getting an undefined error.
the code is written on JS and then build using Phonegap and realesed as an APK for android, while debugging it we get "windwos.onesignal undefined"
any lead or help would be appriciated
Thank you
(can't post the Chrome debugger message rep 10 is requered :-) )

Comment: Try using https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin i have been using this for Android, iOS

Comment: Could you let us know which version of OneSignal you're using? Also which PhoneGap version and which type (Adobe's PhoneGap Build OR PhoneGap CLI) you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Is `windwos.onesignal` exactly what you have in your code? Or is this a typo in your post?

All calls to OneSignal should be called by with `window.plugins.OneSignal`.

Example:
`window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("key1", "value1");`

Check to make sure `window.plugins` is defined where you're calling OneSignal. It should be called from your `onDeviceReady` function or add a ['deviceready' listener](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) if you don't have this function. Double check your code with [OneSignal's Cordova/PhoneGap install instructions](http://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk-installation).

You can also send your APK to support@onesignal.com and we can help debug your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/phonegap-sdk-overview) Make sure you add plugin

```
> cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
```

And try building it locally.

```
>ionic build android
```

If it works locally there is some issue with you config file.Specify version of plugin in config file. Check your installed plugin version.

```
  <plugin name="com.onesignal.plugins.onesignal" spec="1.9.0" source="pgb" />
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: All plugins with the source="pgb" can no longer be updated by plugin developers since Adobe deprecated their repository for npm. The following should be used if you still need to use the ANT compatible version of OneSignal. 
`<gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin-pgb-compat" source="npm" />`
`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplayservices" source="npm" />`
`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" source="npm" />`

Remove googleplayservice and/or android-support-v4 if you have another plugin already including these.